# What does this `ps` command mean?

Tags: grep, ps

```
 ps -e | grep -c '^'
```

Whatever it means I have 166

I got lost with the '^' and can't remember where I seen it

Answer (score 5):

The `-c` (`--count`) option of `grep` prints the number of matches.

The `^` is a regular expression metacharacter representing the beginning of a line (and does not match any actual character).

Your command shows the count of all processes, as seen by `ps`.

Note that running the same command, removing the `-c` option from `grep`, should display the actual output your count is based on.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought but I questioned myself and though no way...

Answer (score 3):

The caret `^` is a regular expression [line anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi) - it restrict matches to occur only at the start of a line.

In the example you give, there is an empty pattern after the anchor, so it matches lines that start with anything - making it equivalent to simply using `grep -c ''`

Either way it returns a line count - equivalent to doing `ps -e | wc -l`

Comment: Grep -c don't output any results for me, and ps | wc -l outputs 4 compared to ps -e | grep -c '^' outputs 166

Comment: @hellomoto apologies I didn't mean to imply that `ps` and `ps -e` would give the same results - obviously they won't. I meant that `ps  <whatever options> | grep -c ''` would be equivalent to `ps <same options> | wc -l`